# How to set my azure function's Platform with Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions

I am trying to change my Azure function's Platform to 64 bit to be compatible with a new dll or project needs. I just have not been able to find the corresponding terraform key to set this azure function field.
The problem is that terraform is currently defaulting to 32 bit, so whenever I deploy the field changes.[image]
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

I've tried poking around with some app_settings keys from [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings), but none of them seem obviously connected to the platform version. I have also tried looking at the keys here [terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_function_app)  and none of those jump out to me either.

Here is my terraform not showing app_settings

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "plan" {
  count               = length(var.resource_groups)
  name                = "${var.name}-asp${count.index + 1}"
  location            = var.resource_groups[count.index].location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_groups[count.index].name
  kind                = "FunctionApp"

  sku {
    tier = var.app_service_plan_tier
    size = var.app_service_plan_size
  }

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "function" {
  count                     = length(azurerm_app_service_plan.plan.*)
  name                      = "${var.name}${count.index + 1}"
  location                  = azurerm_app_service_plan.plan[count.index].location
  resource_group_name       = azurerm_app_service_plan.plan[count.index].resource_group_name
  app_service_plan_id       = azurerm_app_service_plan.plan[count.index].id
  storage_account_name      = var.storage_account_name
  storage_account_access_key = var.storage_account_access_key
  app_settings              = local.app_settings
  version                   = "~2"
  https_only                = true
  tags                      = var.tags
}
```

Comment: Can you please include the `azurerm_app_service_plan` resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resource that manages the configuration of the worker is the `azurerm_function_app`  resource.

Setting the attribute [use_32_bit_worker_process](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app.html#use_32_bit_worker_process) to true will run the applications in a 32-bit platform, which it's the default value.

Explicitly set `use_32_bit_worker_process` to `false` and be sure to use any other tiers than Free or Shared, as stated in the docs:

> when using an App Service Plan in the Free or Shared Tiers use_32_bit_worker_process must be set to true.

Comment: [azurerm_app_service_plan](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service_plan) does not control the bitness of the worker. Its the now deprecated azurerm_function_app

Comment: Made a mistake while copying the resource, yes, the `azurerm_app_service_plan` doesn't control the worker setting, it's the `azurerm_function_app` resource. I've updated the answer. While you're correct about the deprecated resource, none of these resources will be removed until version 4.0 is released.

Answer (score 1):

javierlga is correct,

set use_32_bit_worker_process to false inside site_config block.

```
site_config = {
  use_32_bit_worker_process  = false
}
```

More info:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app#use_32_bit_worker_process

Comment: This is a good call out incase anyone looks at this in the future and does not know where to put it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to set the bitness of your worker in the [azurerm_windows_function_app](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_function_app) resource.

Set `use_32_bit_worker` to false.

Note: azurerm_function_app is deprecated and has been superseeded by `windows_function_app` or `azurerm_linux_function_app`

Comment: The user is using `azurerm_function_app` and `azurerm_app_service_plan` resources not `azurerm_windows_function_app`.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but we will continue to use `azurerm_function_app` for slightly longer as it is a pretty big lift to change all of our function apps.